# BASH for loop to test list for username

Tags: bash, for-loop

For this specific problem I need to write a script that checks for the existence of a list, checks the list to see if the username given through the command line exists and if it doesn't, it appends it to the list. I've seen similar questions like this but haven't found one that specifically uses the for loop. I just started learning BASH the other day so any help or a push in the right direction will be of great help. Here is what I have so far (with syntax errors)

```
#! /bin/bash
user=$1

if  [ list.txt -f ]; then  
    echo "The list does not exist"

    for v in $(cat list.txt)
    do
    if [ $v -eq $user ]; then 
            echo "That username already exists!"

    elif
    echo $user >> list.txt ; then

   else  echo "That file does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Your professor wants you to reinvent `grep` with a `for` loop in Bash? I'm sorry, but that's just sick. A `while` loop might have some merit, but this ... Ugh.

Comment: The reason that none of them use a for loop is because a for loop is incorrect for iterating over the lines in a file. Use a while loop.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm glad I learned how to do it with the for loop. I'll definitely make my life easier by using grep in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$1

if  [ ! -f "list.txt" ]; then
  echo "The list does not exist."
else
  for v in $(cat list.txt)
  do
    # user found
    if [ "$v" = "$user" ]; then
      echo "That username already exists!"
      exit $?
    fi
  done
fi

# user not found
echo $user >> "list.txt"
```

Notes on Bash:

- When comparing strings in bash, you'll want to use the `=` operator ([see this list](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)).
- Not a bad idea to use quotes (`" "`) for file names (in case the file names have spaces, etc.)
- `elif` needs to have a condition, if you are going to use it ([see this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) and search for `elif`).

Hope this helps a little; knowing Bash can be pretty useful!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping clarify this. I had been staring at it for too long and it all stopped making sense :)

Comment: Hey, no problem; I know how staring at code can go, sometimes.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, as well!  And... just for future reference, if you ever get an answer to your question (that ended up working for you,) don't forget to accept the answer (and/or upvote answers that did help!) :)

Answer (score 0):

Loops are for people with nothing better to do.

```
if [ -f list.txt ] && grep -q -x -F "$user" list.txt
then
  echo "Username exists"
else
  echo "$user" >> list.txt
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the alternatives I came across, unfortunately, I am required to use the for loop in this assignment.

Comment: Or even `fgrep -qx "$username" list.txt || echo "$username" >>list.txt`